# Auto mirror of human head

Tags: mirror

[enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmmqKHEN8ib3hFAfyxQfWqL14o8n?e=ydicZ2)
I attempted to use Auto Mirror on human head but working on surface of a mesh  were not adapted to other side on a mesh.
What should I do?[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use the Mirror modifier **and** Auto Mirror at the same time. In any case you seem to have Auto Mirror set to the 'Z' direction instead of 'X' which is the direction you should be mirroring, From the patterns on the surface of your model you appear to have overlapping faces anyway which will also cause problems but we'd need to see your Blend file to see exactly what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ if it isn't larger than 30Meg following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess *AutoMirror* will work as long as your object is symmetrical, to recover the symmetry try a *Mesh > Symmetrize*:

[image]

Choose the wanted axis in the *Operator Box*:

[image]